# using indexed arrays as a format map of input data in gawk

Tags: arrays, awk, gawk

So basically i have a file with pipe separated lines, i would like to cut the field's content when they go over a certain length, so i have set a max length for each field.
I'm using arrays in order to store the value of the max length for each field:

```
    gawk -F"|" -- '

BEGIN {
    map[1]=10
    map[2]=20
    map[3]=60
    map[4]=60
    map[5]=3
    map[6]=60
    map[7]=3

    OFS="|"
}

{
   for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      if (length($i) > map[$i]) {
        $i = substr($i, 1, map[$i])
      }
   }
   print;
}
'
```

The problem here is that there is something wrong with the array, the items all return null or 0 so that all comparisons `if (length($i) > map[$i])` return true and it will empty all fields, 
Whats wrong with my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `(length($i) > map[$i])`  to `(length($i) > map[i])` and `substr($i, 1, map[$i])` to `substr($i, 1, map[i])`
.

Like this:

```
    gawk -F"|" -- '

BEGIN {
    map[1]=10
    map[2]=20
    map[3]=60
    map[4]=60
    map[5]=3
    map[6]=60
    map[7]=3

    OFS="|"
}

{
   for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      if (length($i) > map[i]) {
        $i = substr($i, 1, map[i])
      }
   }
   print;
}
'
```

`$i` refers to the contents of field number `i`, but the contents of that field is *not* the index of `map`.